# Slug is too short - Django

Tags: python, django

Here's a snippet of code in my models.py file:

```
GENRE_CHOICES = (
             ('R', 'Rock'),
             ('B', 'Blues'),
             ('J', 'Jazz'),
             ('P', 'Pop'), 
             ('H', 'Hip-Hop'),    
             )

class Genre(models.Model):
  genre_choices = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENRE_CHOICES)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 100, unique = True)
```

admin.py pre-populates the slug like this:

```
class GenreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("genre_choices",)}
```

In the admin site, I notice that the slug only populates to the first letter. For instance, for rock, only `R` is selected. How do i select the other part of the tuple i.e. Rock instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, change your GENRE_CHOICES dict to something like:

```
 ('rock', 'Rock'),
 ('hip-hop', 'Hip-Hop'),
```

etc etc

Comment: ha! your answer made me realize how dumb my question was. thanks a lot

Comment: well not that much a dumb question. object identifiers should not really contain the object content, this is redundant.

Comment: I'd rather have "rock" than "r" in my database. What would be "r" ? "Rock" or "Rap" or "Rumba" ? :D

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an abandonned bug :

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9983

The bugfix was postponed from 1.2 to 1.3 due to regressions,and was never appplied to 1.3
Seems like you can fix that by tweaking the Django code, or by applying the patch provided inthe ticket. Not sure though it will work with your Django version.

In the meantime, you can try to use object_identifiers that will correctly prepopulate your SlugField :

```
GENRE_CHOICES = (
             ('rock', 'Rock'),
             ('blues', 'Blues'),
             ('jazz', 'Jazz'),
             ('pop', 'Pop'), 
             ('hip-hop', 'Hip-Hop'),    
             )
```

Sidenote: you have max_length=1 in your CharField. Maybe the bug was actually fixed but the SlugField only takes a single charbecause of that. Not sure about that though. **Edit: this (`max_length=1`) actually doesn't change anything. Thanks to jpic**

Comment: He has max_length=1 on the genre CharField, and max_length=100 on the slug CharFild.

Comment: Well maybe the SlugField reads only a single char from the CharField because the CharField is actually limited to a single char.

Comment: The SlugField class does not read any char from any CharField class, says the source code (see django/db/models/__init__.py, class SlugField). Also, django/contrib/admin/static/js/prepopulate.js does not care about field lengths. So we can de facto eliminate this possibility.

Answer (score -1):

enlarge the max_length,

```
genre_choices = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENRE_CHOICES)
```

to

```
genre_choices = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENRE_CHOICES)
```

may helps, just guess.